# Java Android Application

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, android-design-library

I want to one Simple UI Design in `Android Emulator`.

Whats Needed:

Java `Eclipse`, then any SDK Please Suggest me for that ?

Answer (score 2):

Follow [this link](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) and follow the instructions to set up eclipse and android sdk tools.

To start do the "hello world" tutorial and the "Hello, Views" tutorial in the android sdk page that should put you in the right track of how you should create apps easily :)